# UI Automation how to perform swipe gesture

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, instruments, ui-automation, ui-testing

I want to perform swipe gesture on UITableView cell with automation script. I tried recording this action but I get this:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[1].cells()[2].buttons()[0].scrollToVisible();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the commands I was looking for: `dragInsideWithOptions()` or `dragFromToForDuration;`

Use it like this `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[1].cells()[2].dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.0, y:0.1}, endOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.1}, duration:0.25});`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The app just registers a long tap and not a swipe.